# How to loop for choosing data in Jupyter Notebook by Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 columns in data frames.
Column 1 = Source
Column 2 = Target

My data source

```
Source Target
  A      B
  W      X
  B      C
  C      D
  C      Z
  A      Z
  Z      Y
```

Input = A, The output should be display as below.

```
Source Target
  A      B
  B      C
  C      D
  C      Z
  A      Z
  Z      Y
```

I try to code as below but not finished yet.

```
In [1]: 

    a = input()
            b = []
            for Source, Target in zip(data.Source,data.Target):
                if Source == a:
                   b.append(True)
                else:
                   b.append(False)
```

Input = A

```
In [2]: is_long = pd.Series(b)
        is_long
Out [2]: 0   True 
         1   False
         2   True
         3   True
         4 ...

In [3]: data[is_long]
Out [3]: Source Target
           A      B
           B      C
           C      D
           C      Z
           A      Z
           Z      Y
```

Comment: I compared your source data with the expected output.
The only difference is that row with *Source == 'W'* does not appear in the output.
On the other hand, the piece of code you included "passes"
only rows with *Source == 'A'* (you wrote *Input = A*).
How do you explain this discrepance?

Comment: I want Target of Source  to find continued Target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, the idea is:

- try in turn each vertice from the source DataFrame,
- the current vertice is "OK" when its *Source* node has been visited
  before,
- the visited list contains initially only the node given by the user and
  should be extended by *Target* node of each checked vertice.

Start from defining the following class:

```
class Visitor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clear()

    def addNode(self, node):
        if not self.isVisited(node):
            self._nodes.append(node)

    def isVisited(self, node):
        return node in self._nodes

    def clear(self):
        self._nodes = []
```

This class keeps a register of visited nodes. It will be used soon.

Then define a function checking the "continuation criterion" for the current
row:

```
def isContinued(row, vs):
    res = vs.isVisited(row.Source)
    if res:
        vs.addNode(row.Target)
    return res
```

The first argument is the current row and the second is a *Visitor* object.

Then run:

```
vs = Visitor()
vs.addNode(a)
df[df.apply(isContinued, axis=1, vs=vs)]
```

The first line creates a *Visitor* object.
The second adds the "starting node" (just given by the user) to the
"visited list".
Then `df.apply(isContinued, axis=1, vs=vs)` creates a *Boolean* vector
- the continuation criteria for edges.

As *isContinued* function is applied to subsequent edges, the "visited list"
is extended with *Target* node.
The (just updated) visited list is then used to compute the continuation
criteria for subsequent edges.

The result is a list of edges meeting the continuation criterion.